# How to filter out double text detection with OpenCV and Java?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to detect text on an image and I think it works but sometimes I get results like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvBQ0.jpg).

How can I get rid of the small detection inside the big detection?

I draw the contours bounding boxes.

Comment: Add your code and people will be more able to help.

Comment: I did not add my code because I just have an ArrayList of Rects and that's all. So I want to filter out the overlapping small ones.

Answer (score 1):

You have the bounding boxes for each detection. If one bounding box is inside the other take only the text that is connected to the outside bounding box.

Lets say the big bounding box has the parameters box1 = (X1,Y1,width1,height1) and the small bounding box has the parameters box2 = (X2,Y2,width2,height2) (Where the coordinate of the bounding box is the lower left coordinate).

Then:

```
If (X1 < X2) && (Y1 < Y2) && (X1+width1 > X2 + width2) && (Y1+height1 > Y2 + height2)
```

Then box2 is insied box1